# How to loop over images

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to loop over my images folder and display them on the screen.
Like i have this

```
<section id="photos">
        <a target="_blank" href="images/1.jpg">
            <img src="images/1.jpg">
        </a>
</section>
```

And all of my images are with numbers so my question is how to loop that code through all the pictures like: 1,2,3,4,5 etc without typing it n times.

Comment: You can load them in javascript and then append in dom.

Comment: Can you show me how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client-side Javascript does not have access to the harddrive on your server, so without a server-side programming language, you can't actually loop over the images.

What you *can* do is assume that the server has a certain amount of images, and request them.

```
var section = document.getElementById('photos');
var elements = '';

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { // Loops through images 1 - 5
  var imgSrc = 'images/' + i + '.jpg';
  var element = '<a target="_blank" href="' + imgSrc + '"><img src="' + imgSrc + '"></a>';
  elements += element;
}

section.innerHTML = elements;
```

Comment: Yea I know that was my idea , thank you for this, can you show me just how to use that in the section ( sorry for the dumb question).

Comment: Although this might work for your purpose, it's worth noting that it is never a good idea for client side code to assume anything about the data with production apps. e.g. if you assume you have 5 images, every time you want to add a new image you will have to do a release

Comment: Totally got what you mean! Thanks for your reply , it's a specific project and  i just needed to know how to do it with js.